# Check if time between 2 dates intersects time between 2 other dates

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

What is an efficient way to check if anywhere between 2 dates intersects anywhere between 2 other dates without having to check each second in between dates and checking if the second is in between the other two dates?

Answer (score 1):

Say you have:
time `t` and intervals `[a-b] [c-d]`, if they are sorted like:

- a < d
- a < b
- c < d

Then you may check if `t`is inside b and c, and the check if b > c, then the whole thing is true, else - no.
And as a fast sight, I can't yet think up something better then full check if they are not sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be rephrased like this.

Check if any of two dates c1 and c2 are in between the two dates d1 and d2.

```
// assuming d1 is before d2
BOOL intersects = 
   ([d1 compare:c1] == NSOrderedAscending  &&
    [d2 compare:c1] == NSOrderedDescending)
    ||
   ([d1 compare:c2] == NSOrderedAscending &&
    [d2 compare:c2] == NSOrderedDescending)
    || [d1 compare:c1] == NSOrderedEqual
    || [d1 compare:c2] == NSOrderedEqual
    || [d2 compare:c1] == NSOrderedEqual
    || [d2 compare:c2] == NSOrderedEqual;
```

EDIT: alternatively,

```
NSTimeInterval i = [d2 timeIntervalSinceDate:d1];
NSTimeInterval c1i = [c1 timeIntervalSinceDate:d1];
NSTimeInterval c2i = [c2 timeIntervalSinceDate:d1];
BOOL intersects = (c1i >= 0 && c1i <= i) || (c2i >= 0 && c2i <= i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Two intervals `[a, b]` and `[c, d]` have a non-empty intersection if

```
a <= d && c <= b
```

therefore you can check

```
[a compare:d] <= 0 && [c compare:b] <= 0
```

to see if the intervals have any value in common.

(Here I have assumed that the intervals are *ordered*, i.e. that `a <= b` and `c <= d`.)

Answer (score 1):

> What is an efficient way to check if anywhere between 2 dates
>   intersects anywhere between 2 other dates without having to check each
>   second in between dates and checking if the second is in between the
>   other two dates?

You do it the other way. When is it that the first interval doesn't intersect the second?

- When End1 < Start2 (the first interval ends before the second starts)
- When Start1 > End2 (the first interval starts after the second has ended).

So you want

```
 End1 < Start2 OR Start1 > End2  // Condition of non-intersection
```

to be false: i.e. you want

```
 End1 >= Start2 AND Start1 <= End2   // Negation of above
```

to be true.